# SVN with meld and multiple files

Tags: linux, svn, meld

I have a script which name is svn-diff. I use that script to open svn diff to meld:
svn diff --diff-cmd='meld' $1

Then I run it:
svn-diff /path-to-my-svn-directory/

The problem is now that, meld open files one by one, and not all files to tabs. I have to close one file that I can see next file. I want to see all changes in one view without closing other files.

I have tried to modify script here:
svn diff --diff-cmd='svnmeld' $1

And then created svnmeld script:
meld -n $1 $2 &

But got some error from meld.

I don't want to replace 'svn diff' command with external tool, because I am using it quite often.
Meld version is 1.8.4 and svn version is 1.8.8.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: FWIW, Mercurial does this by creating and populating two temp directories and invoking `meld` with those directories as arguments. Just mentioning it to suggest that `svn` _could_ go about it that way. Having said that, @phobic's answer below is correct.

Answer (score 18):

In your SVN directory simply call:

```
meld .
```

Or:

```
meld /path_to_my_svn_dir/
```

meld supports SVN and other VCS out of the box.

Comment: What if I want to compare specific versions, like with `svn diff -r100:120`?

Comment: I think this is not supported by meld. You might be able to write a script using meld and use it with --diff-cmd (see the comment from @Robert Fleming).

Comment: @TorKlingberg here we are: `svn diff --diff-cmd='meld' -r33376:34192 server.js`

Comment: This is fantastic.  All those years wasted!

Comment: @fiorentinoing awesome. do you know the way to diff in such a way that I can move changes to my working copy and save them? something like that is possible for example in IntelliJ

Comment: What happens when you are doing diff against HEAD?